# cloudformation - Is it possible to split a string and assign to property in a list?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, devops, web-application-firewall

How do I split a string and use the value for a property?

For example say I have the following string: `SomeRule1,SomeRule2`.

I want use this string to populate the `exludedRules` property of [`AWS::WAFv2::WebACL ManagedRuleGroupStatement`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-wafv2-webacl-managedrulegroupstatement.html). `excludedRules` is a list of [`ExcludedRule`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-wafv2-webacl-excludedrule.html) objects that contains a single `Name` property. How can I use the splitted string value for the `Name` property?

Answer (score 3):

Sadly you **can't do this** automatically using plain CloudFormation just by having `SomeRule1,SomeRule2`, because [ExcludedRule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-wafv2-webacl-excludedrule.html) is not a simple list of strings. It is **list of objects**, in the form of:

```
  ExcludedRules: 
    - Name: SomeRule1
    - Name: SomeRule2
```

Generation of such a **list of objects** would require some looping mechanism which is not supported in CloudFormation. You have to explicitly list all these rules, one by one.

But if you really must **automate** such process, you could develop a [CloudFormation macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html) which would give you the ability to loop and construct such structures. [Custom resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) can also be used to automate such operations.

Both the macro and the custom resource would require you to develop a special **lambda function** which would perform the looping based on your `SomeRule1,SomeRule2` and construct valid `ExcludedRules`.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with other answer, can't dynamically add Rules since its not a simple List of Strings. But if we know exact no of rules. we can use split and select.

Lets take this parameter:

```
Parameters:
  Rules:
    Type: String
    Description: "list of rules seperate by comma"
    Default: "my-rule-1,my-rule-2"
```

We can use it like this:

```
          ExcludedRules:
            - Name: !Select
                - 0
                - !Split [",", !Ref Rules]
            - Name: !Select
                - 1
                - !Split [",", !Ref Rules]
```